# Typo3 7.6 MySQL Version

Tags: mysql, typo3

I setup a new site with Typo3 7.6. I set it up with a mysql 5.1 database. The requirement for that typo3 version is normally mysql 5.5+.
By now everything is running without any problems and our provider will update to the new mysql version in the next 2-3 month.

What could be problematic with the current mysql 5.1 version? As far is I tested it everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no major problem using mysql 5.1 with typo3 7 but if you need to use SSL there was a bug reported in mysql5.1
against OpenSSL could be tricked not to check server certificates. (Bug #47320, CVE-2009-4028)
and InnoDB support integrated as plugin in 5.5 that adds improvement in performance when your application uses innnodb more so for Typo3 7 onwards better to use 5.5 other reasons are UTF-8 support enhancement.
But there are no crashing report running Typo3 7+ on mysql 5.1 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't need SSL so there should be no problem from that site. I hope the provider will update the mysql version soon.